# Error Exporting STL --insufficient elements to export

Tags: plotting, export, graphics3d, parametric-functions, 3d-printing

I am trying to export the following code as an STL file:

```
mobius = 
ParametricPlot3D[{(1 + 1/2 v Cos[u/2]) 
Cos[u], (1 + 1/2 v Cos[u/2]) Sin[u], 1/2 v Sin[u/2]}, 
{u, 0,2\[Pi]}, {v, -1, 1}, Mesh -> None, PlotStyle -> Thickness[.05]]
```

However, when I export (see next line) I get the following error:

```
Export["mobius.stl", mobius, stl]
```

"Export::inselem: There are insufficient elements to export to STL format."

And it fails.

Other people seem to have been successful with exporting STL, so any ideas why this isn't working?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest that: 1) You take the introductory [Tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) now! 2) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)! 3) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise.

Comment: Try `Export["mobius.stl", mobius]`.

Comment: I did; that completes, but the STL does not appear in an external STL viewer.

Comment: I can open it with Photoshop, where it gives me top and side views in B&W.  In any case, adding`stl` as a third argument is causing your error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Export["mobius.stl", mobius] creates the desired file, which I can open with Photoshop CC, producing B&W top and side views.  Presumably, more specialized software would give a true 3D image, although still B&W.